# which node of Elasticsearch cluster (master , data, ingest ) gather data from logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have 3 nodes of Elasticsearch in my cluster. how they connect to each other and how to set output filter of my logstash to send data to ES cluster(actually which node is responsible for gathering data)?

Answer (score 0):

actually Logstash send data to cluster and you can check it from /etc/logstash/conf.d/*. ingest node is responsible for indexing documents on cluster. by default all nodes are ingest. you can have dedicated ingest node but with 3 nodes you don't need.